# Rename a diverged folder, and merge back to master

Tags: git

In the codebase I'm working on we have a legacy application ("`OldApp`") that was recently majorly uplifted and upgraded ("`NewApp`") in its own branch.

Now, it has been decided that we can't immediately replace `OldApp` with `NewApp`, so we'll need to continue supporting `OldApp` for a while until we can get enough customers migrated to `NewApp`.

Since both share the same backend server code, keeping things in two separate branches isn't overly maintainable in the long term, (and we don't necessarily want to merge changes in `OldApp` over the top of `NewApp` when the codebase has diverged) so we'd like to get everything merged back into our master branch once `NewApp` reaches release.

So, in `Master` we have

`ClientApps\ClientApplication` - which contains the Old code

and in `NewBranch` we have

`ClientApps\ClientApplication` - which contains the new code (which is based on the old)

what we want to end up with is a single branch containing

`ClientApps\OldApp`  - containing the files and history of ClientApplication from master

and

`ClientApps\NewApp` - containing the files and history from the new branch.

How is this achievable with git?  I basically don't want to end up accidentally merging the new code into the old codebase.  Whilst I could just take a copy of the whole newapp folder and paste it back into master, that would lose all history, which is something I'd rather not have to do.

Comment: Have you tried just renaming them in each branch and then merge? When the name is different, there should be no conflict.

Comment: I was concerned that it would see the rename, and just consider this part of the merge (i.e. the `oldapp` folder would just get renamed and merged into as part of the merge)

Comment: So have you actually tried it? In the (improbable) case it fails, you can go back to any existing commit in any time.

Comment: Yes, I just did. It ended up with OldApp containing the code and history, and NewApp being left behind unimported

Comment: Are there any conflicting changes in `NewBranch` outside the discussed directories?

Comment: Nothing major - a few changes in the core server code that needs merging back anyway, but I don't think there's anything that conflicts.  I can currently safely merge `master` back into `NewBranch` anyway, since, as of yet, the old app code in master has been mostly untouched for six months

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that OldApp is being developed in the `master` branch and NewApp in the `newapp` branch, and you want to have both OldApp and NewApp in `master`, the following sequence of commands will do what you want:

```
git checkout newapp
git mv ClientApps/ClientApplication ClientApps/NewApp
git commit -m "ClientApplication -> NewApp"
git checkout master
git mv ClientApps/ClientApplication ClientApps/OldApp
git commit -m "ClientApplication -> OldApp"
mkdir ClientApps/NewApp
git checkout newapp ClientApps/NewApp
git commit -m "Imported ClientApps/NewApp from the newapp branch"
```

Note however that ClientApps/NewApp will not have any prior history on the master branch (though its initial commit message clearly indicates where it came from).

**EDIT 1:** In order to connect NewApp's history on the `master` branch to its history on the `newapp` branch also do the following:

```
parent1=$(git rev-parse master^)
parent2=$(git rev-parse newapp)
git filter-branch --parent-filter "echo '-p $parent1 -p $parent2'" -- master^..master
```

Comment: That's basically the same as just manually copy/pasting the code, though -  I really wanted to find a method that maintains the history of both versions

Comment: I gave that a try, and seem to only end up with all the files in master all being tied to the last commit (the folder rename) from the new branch.

Admittedly I'm doing this on windows, so had to change the commands a little, but I think it was otherwise correct.  (~1s instead of ^?s)

Comment: I now realise that is technically correct, as I forgot git doesn't carry over history when you rename a folder, so I guess I need that to happen, too!

Comment: @benjymous So does my answer solve your problem or not? If now, what are your exact requirements?

Comment: it solves the question I asked, but not really solves what I need - since the act of renaming the folder wipes history anyway, we only get the "renamed" entry (so it needs to pull over the history before the rename)

Comment: @benjymous How do you judge that the history was wiped away? By the output of `git log ClientApps/NewApp/somefile`? If you provide the `--follow` switch to `git log` it will show the history beyond renames.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to test this and got the expected results.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git mv ClientApplication/ oldApp
$ git commit -m "move old"
$ git checkout NewBranch
$ git mv ClientApplication/ newApp
$ git commit -m "move new"
$ git checkout master
$ git merge NewBranch
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 newApp/test.txt | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 newApp/test.txt
$ ls
newApp/  oldApp/
$ git log --graph --oneline
*   e5c6b12 Merge branch 'NewBranch'
|\
| * 51e4806 move new
| * 1a5703d new-changes
* | 70544c7 move old
* | d55002d old-changes
|/
* dbea2e7 old
```

Comment: Did you create ClientApplication directory after forking?

Comment: No, you haven’t told it did not exist. I’ll check it.

Comment: I am not the author of the question. I just think that you should have a merge conflict if ClientApplication existed before branching. At least that's what I am seeing when doing a similar experiment on my side.

Comment: @Leon Sorry, it’s just that I saw your name on this page before... :-) However, now I checked both alternatives and both succeeded.

Comment: Just tried that myself - it seems to consider every single file a conflict (since it was deleted in both branches in the original location) which is a bit of a pain on a large project

Comment: Have you used `git mv`? If the files are marked as deleted, something went wrong _before_ the merge.